# Прослушать порт FreeBSD и выполнить команду

Tags: freebsd

необходимо следующее..
к примеру порты 20, 25, 30, 35 открыты и ждут соединения.. некий демон слушает кто ломится на порты и выполняет команду с ip адресом клиента..

есть portknocking  но он не дает нужного эффекта, так как там действие выполняется только после последовательности простукивания портов..

на чем сделать такого демона? perl? или..? куда копать? может есть у кого наработки?

Comment: А tcpd тут никак не подойдёт?

Comment: А не про `xinetd` ли речь идет?

Answer (score 1):

`inetd` / `xinetd` много умеют для запуска и реагирования на соединения извне.
Иногда через них запускаются ненагруженные сервисы, не имеющие своих демонов.
Постоянно в памяти висит процесс `inetd` / `xinetd`, а при появлении входящего соединения, запускается указанная программа.